# Using Muiltiple DAO Recordsets in MS Access

Tags: vba, dao

first post so be as gentle as possible! :)

I'm creating a new database in Access to update our e-commerce software (also Access based).

We receive 3 feeds from suppliers, all CSV files with slightly different formatting. I've imported the feeds successfully using linked tables and can (I think) refresh the data from the files as necessary programatically.

I've created a 'CurrentProducts' table which includes all the products which are live on our site at the moment.

I'd like to take each product code from the CurrentProducts table in turn, look it up in each supplier feed, calculate our sell price based on our buy price, work out which supplier offers the cheapest price and then update the CurrentProducts table accordingly.

I've used VBA often in Excel before for Macro purposes, but I've never really touched DAO Recordsets in Access so I admit that I don't really know what I'm doing!

I've got the code so far below. There are around 17,900 records in the CurrentProducts table, nearly 51,000 records in the 'Ingram' table, nearly 15,000 records in the ScanSource table and around 3,000 records in the Varlink table.

I've left the code running for 5-10 minutes and while the code does seem to be working, it's going incredibly slowly. I can only assume there must be a quicker/easier way to access the data in the recordsets than what I'm doing at the moment.

So over to you guys, shall I scrap all this and start again or can it be tweaked from here?

Thank you.

```
Private Sub Command0_Click()

Dim var As DAO.Recordset
Dim ing As DAO.Recordset
Dim scan As DAO.Recordset
Dim curr As DAO.Recordset
Dim filtvar As DAO.Recordset
Dim filtscan As DAO.Recordset
Dim filting As DAO.Recordset
Dim db As Database
Dim varSQL As String, ingSQL As String, scanSQL As String, currSQL As String
Dim prodcode As String
Dim varPrice As Double, ingPrice As Double, scanPrice As Double, currPrice As Double

DoCmd.Hourglass True

Set db = CurrentDb

currSQL = "select ProductCode, Price from CurrentProducts"
varSQL = "select ProductCode, (Price*1.25) as CalcPrice from Varlink"
ingSQL = "select ProductCode, (Price*1.25) as CalcPrice from Ingram"
scanSQL = "select ProductCode, (Price*1.25) as CalcPrice from ScanSource"

Set curr = db.OpenRecordset(currSQL)
Set var = db.OpenRecordset(varSQL)
Set ing = db.OpenRecordset(ingSQL)
Set scan = db.OpenRecordset(scanSQL)

curr.MoveLast 'Needed to get the accurate number of records

'Show the progress bar
SysCmd acSysCmdInitMeter, "Working...", curr.RecordCount

curr.MoveFirst

Do While Not curr.EOF
prodcode = curr!ProductCode

var.Filter = "[ProductCode] = " & "'" & prodcode & "'"
Set filtvar = var.OpenRecordset

ing.Filter = "[ProductCode] = " & "'" & prodcode & "'"
Set filting = ing.OpenRecordset

scan.Filter = "[ProductCode] = " & "'" & prodcode & "'"
Set filtscan = scan.OpenRecordset

usevarprice = 0
useingprice = 0
usescanprice = 0

If filtvar.EOF And filtvar.BOF Then
Else
    varPrice = filtvar!CalcPrice
    varPrice = Round(varPrice, 0)
    usevarprice = 1
End If

If filting.EOF And filting.BOF Then
Else
    ingPrice = filting!CalcPrice
    ingPrice = Round(ingPrice, 0)
    useingprice = 1
End If

If filtscan.EOF And filtscan.BOF Then
Else
    scanPrice = filtscan!CalcPrice
    scanPrice = Round(scanPrice, 0)
    usescanprice = 1
End If

If usevarprice = 1 And useingprice = 1 And usescanprice = 1 Then
    If varPrice < ingPrice And varPrice < scanPrice Then
        newPrice = varPrice
    ElseIf ingPrice < varPrice And ingPrice < scanPrice Then
        newPrice = ingPrice
    Else
        newPrice = scanPrice
    End If
ElseIf usevarprice = 1 And useingprice = 1 And usescanprice = 0 Then
    If varPrice < ingPrice Then
        newPrice = varPrice
    Else
        newPrice = ingPrice
    End If
ElseIf usevarprice = 1 And useingprice = 0 And usescanprice = 1 Then
    If varPrice < scanPrice Then
        newPrice = varPrice
    Else
        newPrice = scanPrice
    End If
ElseIf usevarprice = 0 And useingprice = 1 And usescanprice = 1 Then
    If scanPrice < ingPrice Then
        newPrice = scanPrice
    Else
        newPrice = ingPrice
    End If
Else
    If usevarprice = 1 Then
        newPrice = varPrice
    ElseIf useingprice = 1 Then
        newPrice = ingPrice
    ElseIf usescanprice = 1 Then
        newPrice = scanPrice
    End If
End If

curr.Edit
curr!Price = newPrice
curr.Update

curr.MoveNext

n = n + 1

'Update the progress bar
SysCmd acSysCmdUpdateMeter, n

'Keep the application responding (optional)
DoEvents
Loop

curr.Close: Set curr = Nothing
var.Close: Set var = Nothing
ing.Close: Set ing = Nothing
scann.Close: Set scan = Nothing

'Remove the progress bar
SysCmd acSysCmdRemoveMeter

'Show the normal cursor again
DoCmd.Hourglass False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider this query, to use it just cut and paste into SQL view of the query design window.

```
SELECT c.productcode,
       c.price,
       s.supfile,
       s.calcprice
FROM   currentproducts c
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT "varlink"        AS supfile,
                         productcode,
                         ( price * 1.25 ) AS CalcPrice
                  FROM   varlink
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT "ingram"         AS supfile,
                         productcode,
                         ( price * 1.25 ) AS CalcPrice
                  FROM   ingram
                  UNION ALL
                  SELECT "scansource"     AS supfile,
                         productcode,
                         ( price * 1.25 ) AS CalcPrice
                  FROM   scansource) AS s
              ON c.productcode = s.productcode
```

If the query shows data of interest to you, you just need to get the minimum value per product code from the union table. This is not too difficult in SQL.

For example, you can save the union query as a query and then manipulate the data.

```
SELECT u.supfile,
       u.productcode,
       u.calcprice
FROM   MyUnion u
WHERE  (( ( u.calcprice ) IN (SELECT TOP 1 calcprice
                                 FROM   MyUnion b
                                 WHERE  b.productcode = u.productcode
                                 ORDER  BY calcprice) ));
```

This query can also be included as a derived table, in the same way as the query above, so you can compare the various low prices with the current price, however, this query will give duplicates when two suppliers have the same prices.

The decision process may not be quite as simple as updating where the price is lowest, however, if nothing else, working with sql and vba will dramatically cut down on the processing time and the number of recordsets.

Comment: Hi Remou, thanks for this! So if I'm understanding this correctly, the query shows me the product code and the current price. I'm not quite sure how, but does the query then show which price out of all 3 suppliers is the cheapest (and the relevant supplier)? Is it something to do with the union I'm missing? Just want to understand so I don't have to bug you as much :)

Comment: It does not show the cheapest yet, I needed to find out of the data shown was relevant before moving to the next stage because i do not have any sample data. It should show you the product, current price, a supplier file name and a calcprice, from that we can move to selected the minimum calcprice, but I would like to get some sample data.

Comment: Hi Remou, no worries about the sample data, how should I send it over to you?

Comment: Edit you post and just cut and paste a little information from each table into your post above. Do not worry too much about getting the layout exact. You can mess about to hide any real information. It is mostly about the fields and the type of data they contain.

Comment: Hi Remou, there's too many characters to add this after my post, so I hope you can make use of it here instead.

Comment: Grr won't let me edit the comment now! Hopefully this will work: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8Z9PZ332oCnemR1ckh6ZXlWZXc You are only allowed 30000 characters in the initial post, the amount of data I had took me over that amount (by about 15000 lol)

Comment: ProductCode in the current products sample data does not relate to any of the data in the other files, yet your VBA seems to suggest that it does.

Comment: It does! CurrentProducts = ProductCode, Ingram = ProductCode, Varlink = Manufacturer Code and ScanSource = Manufacturer Part #. As I said I had renamed the fields during the linked table import, however I've changed my import method now and I'm just reading the CSVs straight into a table, so the fields from the CSVs are being used.

Comment: The product codes in currentproducts sample data are like so: 10993, 10996, product codes in scansource are like so: CD-048, in varlink: MEZ1000-MDK-D-S-UK, 901801013, in ingram: JC-PR2-XP0R. There is not one productcode in any of the three files that matches the productcodes in the current products file.

Comment: That is just sample data, do you need specific sample data that is matching acorss all tables? As I said there's over 50000 records in the Ingram table alone, so it's highly likely that I've picked non-matching records.

Comment: The whole point is to just choose a small set of records so that I can suggest sample SQL. Have you tried any of the sql I suggested? Is it getting you anywhere?

Comment: Yes I've used some of your code and it is very useful, however having now changed all my fieldnames I'm having trouble! Please see this file: https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8Z9PZ332oCnVFg2NjBadzhIVzg

Comment: Changed the query SQL to read the following and it now works! SELECT c.[Product Reference], c.Price, s.supfile, s.calcprice FROM Product AS c LEFT JOIN (SELECT "varlink" AS supfile, [Manufacturer Code] as productcode, ( [Buy Price] * 1.25 ) AS CalcPrice FROM tbl_Varlink UNION ALL SELECT "ingram" AS supfile, ProductCode, ( Price * 1.25 ) AS CalcPrice FROM   tbl_Ingram UNION ALL SELECT "scansource" AS supfile, [Manufacturer Part #] as productcode, ( CONTRACT_PRICE * 1.25 ) AS CalcPrice FROM tbl_scansource)  AS s ON c.[Product Reference] = s.productcode;

Comment: But when I run this line in VBA qrySQL = "SELECT u.supfile, u.[Product Reference], u.calcprice FROM qryGetUpdatedPrices u WHERE  (( ( u.calcprice ) IN (SELECT TOP 1 calcprice FROM qryGetUpdatedPrices b WHERE b.ProductCode = u.ProductCode ORDER  BY calcprice) ));"
Set qry = db.OpenRecordset(qrySQL) I get an error message along the lines of 'Unexpected number of arguments, expected 2'. Any ideas?

Comment: It's actually: "Too few parameters, expected 2"

Comment: Two few parameters is often due to misspelled field names. Does the query run in the query design window?

Comment: Yes it does, but I've just found it! b.ProductCode = u.ProductCode should be b.[Product Reference] = u.[Product Reference], let me just run it now!

Comment: I'm getting the too few parameters error again. Is it to do with the spaces in the field names? This is the full code I'm using now https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8Z9PZ332oCnWjNySkFBQksxVVk

Comment: All I can say is does the query work when you paste it into the query design window? That is the best way of debugging problems with queries.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a temporary table (temp_prod) and dumped all the products from all 3 suppliers into the table. I then used this query:

```
SELECT a.productcode, a.buyprice, a.listprice, a.source FROM temp_prod AS a WHERE a.buyprice in (Select top 1 buyprice from temp_prod b where a.productcode = b.productcode order by buyprice)
```

To open a recordset containing the cheapest price for each product code. I then looped through the recordset, updated a product export table with the new sell price (calculated from the buyprice) and voila. Thanks a lot for your help Remou!